# "Index has bad entries at data rows" error when reading CSV

Tags: r, zoo

I have a .csv file containing stock prices in the below format

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close
3/7/2014 10:15  228.28  236.58  228.23  236.18
3/7/2014 11:15  236.23  241.27  236.09  241.14
3/7/2014 12:15  241.1   246.12  241.1   242.96
3/7/2014 13:15  242.84  243.92  242     242.32
```

When I am running the below script:

```
test <- as.xts(read.zoo(mytest.csv', header=T, fill=T, index.column = 1, row.names=NULL,stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="",format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz=""))
```

The below error is shown

> Error in read.zoo("mydata.csv", header = T, fill = T, index.column =
>   1,  :    index has bad entries at data rows:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you get the `as.xts` function from but I see two small fixes you need to get the data into R.

First you should add an extra variable name for the time since the `read.zoo` function uses the same delimiter as `read.table` so if you want it to work with a header then you need a name for each column.

```
Date     Time   Open    High    Low     Close
3/7/2014 10:15  228.28  236.58  228.23  236.18
3/7/2014 11:15  236.23  241.27  236.09  241.14
3/7/2014 12:15  241.1   246.12  241.1   242.96
3/7/2014 13:15  242.84  243.92  242     242.32
```

Second, you can read in the file above as follows

```
library(zoo)
indata <- read.zoo("mydata.csv", header=TRUE, index.column = 1:2, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="CET")
```

Note that two indices are given since the date/time is split over two columns. Also, I think a `tz` is needed for the date/time conversion to work. In any case the above gives

```
> indata
                      Open   High    Low  Close
2014-03-07 10:15:00 228.28 236.58 228.23 236.18
2014-03-07 11:15:00 236.23 241.27 236.09 241.14
2014-03-07 12:15:00 241.10 246.12 241.10 242.96
2014-03-07 13:15:00 242.84 243.92 242.00 242.32
```

which can be passed to other R functions.

Comment: Thanks, ekstroem. I have added another column for time, but when i runs the above command,this gives me another error as: Error in `[.data.frame`(rval, , j) : undefined columns selected. Pls revert

Comment: Could you show the exact code you're running? And the file

Comment: Date Time Open High Low Close
2013-01-30 10:15 12762.11 12808 12753.05 12758
2013-01-30 11:15 12758.05 12786.45 12740 12744
2013-01-30 12:15 12746.95 12759 12726.35 12740.4
2013-01-30 13:15 12737 12798.65 12735 12786.7
2013-01-30 14:15 12786.5 12824 12762 12801.45 This is the .csv file will around 3000 rows, and the code is same as been written by you above. Rel <- read.zoo("BANKNIFTY1.csv", header=TRUE, index.column = 1:2, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="CET")

Comment: Your date format changed from your original posting. Now you have dates in YYYY-MM-DD before you had them in MM/DD/YYYY so your format isn't working. Also make sure the number of tabs between columns is exactly one.