# read.zoo with date as index in R

Tags: r, csv, xts, zoo

I have xts table like this

```
           Open     High      Low    Close       Volume
2011-09-13     5.80     6.00     5.65     5.97 5.837138e+01
2011-09-14     5.58     5.72     5.52     5.53 6.114598e+01
2011-09-15     5.12     5.24     5.00     5.13 8.014080e+01
2011-09-16     4.82     4.87     4.80     4.85 3.991401e+01
```

And I wrote this table to csv by write.zoo

But now I want to read to R again this table by read.zoo and it doesn't work..

Code below

```
indata <- read.zoo(file = "H:/UsersData/test.csv", header=TRUE, index.column = 1, format="%Y/%m/%d", tz="CET", sep = ',')
```

Still error is

```
Error in read.zoo(file = "test.csv",  : 
  index has 2313 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: What about `format="%Y-%m-%d"` ? What means *doesn't work*? Is there any error message?

Comment: If your table is already available in R, wouldn't be more convenient to save as a [`RDS`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/readRDS) file? I understood that you have R object and then you want to load this R object again to a different session? Using CSV makes sense if you intend to use this table outside R session, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271578/index-has-bad-entries-at-data-rows-error-when-reading-csv  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+read.zoo+bad+entries

Comment: format="%Y-%m-%d still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear as to exactly what the content of `test.csv` is.  The code that generated it is not given, only that `write.zoo` was used, and the file content is not given although maybe it is the first code block in the question?

In the absence of a clear reproducible definition of the input we are assuming that it is as generated reproducibly by the code in the Note at the end.  If the file content looks different than that then the code to read it in will need to be modified accordingly.

In the code below `index = 0` means that the input stores the index in the rownames.

We don't have to specify:

- `"Date"` class index since that is the default
- `format` as yyyy-mm-dd is also the default
- `header` since there is one more data field than heading field so it will automatically assume that the first line is a header

Code:

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo("test.csv", index = 0)
```

### Note

Input file assumed to be generated like this:

```
Lines <- '
           Open     High      Low    Close       Volume
2011-09-13     5.80     6.00     5.65     5.97 5.837138e+01
2011-09-14     5.58     5.72     5.52     5.53 6.114598e+01
2011-09-15     5.12     5.24     5.00     5.13 8.014080e+01
2011-09-16     4.82     4.87     4.80     4.85 3.991401e+01
'
cat(Lines, file = "test.csv")
```